# Are my subclasses causing memory leaks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, subclassing

I'm subclassing UINavigationController and UITableview and for some reason, my views are leaking memory, although I've implemented all of the proper methods and release calls. When I use the native class instead of a subclass, everything works just fine, without leaking.

**EDIT:**

Here's my superclass header:

```
//
//  MBAbstractViewController.h
//  GabbaiHD
//
//  Created by Moshe Berman on 11/24/10.
//  Copyright 2010 MosheBerman.com. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MBAbstractViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *backgroundImageView;
    NSString *announcementText;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *options;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *announcementText;

-(void) setAnnouncementText:(NSString *)text;

@end
```

Superclass implementation:

```
//
//  MBAbstractViewController.m
//  GabbaiHD
//
//  Created by Moshe Berman on 11/24/10.
//  Copyright 2010 MosheBerman.com. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MBAbstractViewController.h"


@implementation MBAbstractViewController

@synthesize type, options, announcementText;

 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIColor *clearColor = [[UIColor alloc] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor: clearColor];
    [clearColor release];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||  interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [announcementText release];
    [options release];
    [type release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Here's my subclass header:

```
//
//  MBAnnouncementViewController.h
//  GabbaiHD
//
//  Created by Moshe Berman on 11/24/10.
//  Copyright 2010 MosheBerman.com. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MBAbstractViewController.h"

@interface MBAnnouncementViewController : MBAbstractViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *announcement;
}

- (void) setAnnouncementText:(NSString *)text withSize:(CGFloat)size;

@end
```

and the subclass implementation:

```
        //
//  MBAnnouncementViewController.m
//  GabbaiHD
//
//  Created by Moshe Berman on 11/24/10.
//  Copyright 2010 MosheBerman.com. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MBAnnouncementViewController.h"
#import "Constants.h"[

@implementation MBAnnouncementViewController

 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [announcement setText:announcementText]; 

    UIImage *slideImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_slide", kTheme]description] ofType:@"png"]];  
    [backgroundImageView setImage:slideImage];
    [slideImage release];   


}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void) setAnnouncementText:(NSString *)text withSize:(CGFloat)size{
    UIFont *font = [[UIFont alloc] fontWithSize:size];
    [announcement setFont:font];
    [font release];
    [announcement setText:text];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [announcementText release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

What could be causing memory leaks in a subclass? Am I missing something? (There is [more relevant code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297367/am-i-leaking-memory-in-my-uiscrollview-implementation).)

Comment: Need more information, show the code you think is leaking.

Comment: Hang on, will do. **EDIT:** done.

Comment: Toss in the header file as well, just need to know the types of your member variables.

Comment: I've posted a screenshot here of a different leak: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316453/uitableview-leaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be alloc'ing `UIColor` in this way:

```
[[UIColor alloc] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0];
```

You've alloc'd the instance without initializing it, then you've called a factory method and lost the reference to the instance you alloc'd.

You'll want to call one of the initializers before calling `colorWithAlphaComponent:`.  I'm not sure what the behaviour will be if you don't do so.  Why not just `[UIColor clearColor];`?

You're making the same mistake with `UIFont` too:

```
UIFont *font = [[UIFont alloc] fontWithSize:size];
```

You should never do this.  The only methods you chain onto `+alloc` should be initializers (which always return whatever was alloc'd).  You're leaking here, and also getting some weird unintended behaviour I dare say.

Also, as David Liu says, you appear to be over-releasing `announcementText` and under-releasing `announcement`, which will cause both a crash and a leak, depending on how lucky you get.

EDIT | Based on your update that shows your header files, there are further issues (not specifically related to leaks).

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *announcementText;
```

You should never retain `NSString*`; instead you should `copy` it.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *announcementText;
```

This is because `NSString*` might actually be a mutable string and be changed later.  You may use `retain` if you're specifically wanting this however.

You also do not need to expressly declare `-setAnnouncementText:` when you have the `@property` `announcementText`.

In your subclass `setAnnouncementText:withSize:` actually does nothing to the `announcementText` ivar, which is confusing I guess.  You'll want to release the `announcement` ivar and fix the issue with `UIColor` and `UIFont` being used incorrectly (which are leaking).

Comment: I didn't notice that before, but I'm wondering how that would even work. Calling a static class method from an instantiated object should result in a crash. He should be using the appropriate init methods, or just use the factory methods alone.

Comment: It worked for me. I did it the way I did because my classes were leaking somehow. I was hoping to minimize it by manually removing as much as possible. I guess it didn't work.

Comment: @Moshe: Well, the way it currently is in the code would leak even more, if it isn't outright crashing. You should be doing either [UIColor alloc] initWithWithAlphaComponent:0.0], or [UIColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0]. You can't mix and match.

Comment: It's not a static class method ;)  It returns whatever the current color is, with a different alpha component.  It's an instance method.

Comment: @Moshe, have you tried running this in Leaks?  That would really help tell you where it's leaking.  You might not even be looking in the right place, though this does definitely leak.

Comment: @d11wtq: Ah, now I get it. Though, wouldn't it still cause a crash, since he's doing an extra release on the autoreleased color/font? Guess it might just be returning nils or something since it hasn't been init-ed yet, making it semi-safe.

Comment: Yeah, that's my feeling.  The extra release on the autoreleased object should (probably) be crashing.  It's certainly millions of times more likely to crash than not crash.  But the over-releasing of `announcementText` should also be crashing, which is also weird.  Seems like there's more to it than just these classes.

Comment: @d11wtq - I've run this in Leaks. There seems to be leaks in a few places. And yes, there are more classes than these.

Comment: I've also made some changes here. Thanks for the input. I'm still nowhere near fixed, but this has helped. Thanks!

Comment: @d11wtq - I'd appreciate some pointer as to how to use Leaks. It shows me where I'm leaking but I don't see why it's a leak. I'm dealing with leaks all over the place and it's quite overwhelming.

Comment: @Moshe: You should try doing static analysis on your code first. It'll tell you a lot more, with the code in its current state. Use the "Build and Analyze" option when building, or simply set it to always analyze on build within your project's options.

Comment: Have you made this same mistake of calling alloc without calling init in other parts of your code? Did you fix the ones I pointed out here? Leaks tells you what leaked, so from there you have to figur out where instances of that class are used.

Answer (score 2):

In your subclass, I notice that you have an "announcement" variable that doesn't seem to show up in your superclass.

I'm assuming that your superclass has the following variables:

```
type
options
announcementText
```

While your subclass has an additional variable:

```
announcement
```

In your dealloc of the subclass, you release `announcementText` (which is also released in the superclass), not `announcement`, which is probably the cause of your leakage.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> ... if your view controller contains
>   outlets (properties or raw variables
>   that contain the IBOutlet keyword),
>   you should use the viewDidUnload
>   method to relinquish ownership of
>   those outlets or any other
>   view-related data that you no longer
>   need.

Try releasing `announcement` in the `viewDidUnload` since it's an IBOutlet, Interface Builder retains it.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [announcement release];
    announcement = nil;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're releasing **announcement**.

Comment: I'm not retaining it. See my header file.

Comment: Edited my answer, since it's an IBOutlet you need to also release it and set to nil in the **viewDidUnload**.

Comment: Usually best practice for an IBOutlet is to set it to nil in 'viewDidUnload' and release it in 'dealloc'

Answer (score 0):

What does 'announcement' represent in your second class?  Is it an IBOutlet(I do not see a synthesize for it)?  If it is a property or IBOutlet you will want to make sure to release it in your dealloc.