# UITableView leaking?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uitableview, memory-leaks

I have a UITableViewController and I set some properties in the `viewDidLoadMethod` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self.parentViewController.parentViewController action:@selector(dismissSettings)] autorelease];
    [self setTitle:@"Gabbai Settings"];

    //Set up the table 
    [self.tableView initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    [self.tableView setRowHeight:65.0];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched];

    [self.tableView.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_settings", kTheme] ofType:@"png"]]]];


}
```

The app shows a UIScrollViewController and a UIButton. When the button is pressed, the app displays a modal UINavigationController and that UINavigationController contains a UITableViewController.

For some reason, Leaks reports some leakage when I show the UITableViewController. However, if I comment out the four lines after `//Set up the table`, everything is fine.

When the four lines are uncommented, the Leaks instrument shows the following:

[image: Screenshot of Leaks Instrument]

I'm not sure what is going on here, but it's really annoying. I've used the same four lines of code before to customize my UITableViewController and this is a new behavior.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out by other answers, your problem is the line:

```
[self.tableView initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

It will create a new `UITableView` object and it will **not** modify `self.tableView` which means that line is totally pointless. It only creates the leak you are experiencing. Remove it and you should be fine.

Comment: How then do I change the style of the table view?

Comment: You can't change the table style when the `UITableView` is created. Are you using a NIB and Interface Builder? Then you can change the style there. Otherwise you can do it in `loadView` or when you are creating the `UITableViewController` by using `initWithStyle:`.

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly release tableView in your dealloc method and see what happens.

Or better yet, clean all -> Build and Analyze, tell us what you see

Comment: Thanks for this great tip. It does work sometimes, but not always.

Comment: If I release tableView, it crashes the next time I try to load it.

Comment: Moshe you're going to need to post more code in order for someone to help you. What you are showing us is a basic object retention problem. If you are still having issues after that, then it could be many other things.

Answer (score 1):

if self.tableview already exists, you don't want to initialize it again. Either initialize it once (which I'm guessing you already did, maybe by loading from a nib) and then if need be, reset the frame here.

Or just alloc/init the tableview here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try defining the uiBarButtonItem as a variable, then assign it to the navigation left bar button item and then release the button

Have you try build & analyze under the Build menu? With 2.0 Objective C sentences its pretty accurate

in addition, you have to be careful with property definition, you are using self.tableView, I assume you you have something like @property(nonatomic, retain)?, in that case, once you alloc, you should release the property in the next line..

Finally, this line is extremely weird: [self.tableView initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; you are trying to initialize a table thats already initialized, because if you don't, self.tableView.frame should be in error. In addition to that, the initWithFrame method returns something that is not being assigned.. I think that you can think a better way to do this

Sorry about the mess, I've been answering this question in the chat, but unfortunately you were disconnected.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an array or dictionary thats leaking, not the tableview.

What is the array that you are using to fill your tableview?

Also, you wont want to `[self.tableVIew initWithFrame`, 
try `[self.tableView setFrameCGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];`

Comment: I'm not using an array, I'm setting everything manually inside `cellForRowAtIndex` method.

Comment: Well thats whats leaking is an array/dictionary somewhere, according to your image of Leaks.

Comment: When I was re-initializing the UITableView, it leaked the contents of the old one, hence the NSArray leakage.